# Can i implement flutter platformview to render android xml layout to flutter widget?

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin

I want to implement exoplayer with exoplayer filter together? any possible ways?.
I am successfully implemented the exoplayer with texture . its working fine .
now I want set the GlFilter on top of exoplayer (texture videoview in flutter). like below

```
ePlayerView = new EPlayerView(this);
    // set SimpleExoPlayer
    ePlayerView.setSimpleExoPlayer(player);
    ePlayerView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    // add ePlayerView to WrapperView
    ((MovieWrapperView) findViewById(R.id.layout_movie_wrapper)).addView(ePlayerView);
    ePlayerView.onResume();
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The thing is , i want to implement a video player with glfilter . so  I want to use [link](https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/ExoPlayerFilter) this library. I have done with exoplayer part. and its run with exoplayer and flutter textureview smoothly. but I am unable to play video with glfilter, because its use a separate layer on top of exoplayer , I think.. is there any solution for that. am planning to build a video editor with flutter. with ffmpeg the realtime preview sucks. so moved to exoplayer